# Why are there leading 0x00 bytes in the subjectPublicKey field of a DER X.509 cert?

Tags: rsa, x.509, asn1

For a simple example, I'm using a 512-bit RSA cert to illustrate my question. The cert can be found in both DER and PEM form [here](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certexamples.htm). I've been going through the certificate using this [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js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the provided link to the decoder already has the cert in question loaded).

For convenience, I've reproduced the hex bytes of the cert below:

```
 1  00000000: 3082 0212 3082 017b 0202 0dfa 300d 0609  0...0..{....0...
 2  00000010: 2a86 4886 f70d 0101 0505 0030 819b 310b  *.H........0..1.
 3  00000020: 3009 0603 5504 0613 024a 5031 0e30 0c06  0...U....JP1.0..
 4  00000030: 0355 0408 1305 546f 6b79 6f31 1030 0e06  .U....Tokyo1.0..
 5  00000040: 0355 0407 1307 4368 756f 2d6b 7531 1130  .U....Chuo-ku1.0
 6  00000050: 0f06 0355 040a 1308 4672 616e 6b34 4444  ...U....Frank4DD
 7  00000060: 3118 3016 0603 5504 0b13 0f57 6562 4365  1.0...U....WebCe
 8  00000070: 7274 2053 7570 706f 7274 3118 3016 0603  rt Support1.0...
 9  00000080: 5504 0313 0f46 7261 6e6b 3444 4420 5765  U....Frank4DD We
10  00000090: 6220 4341 3123 3021 0609 2a86 4886 f70d  b CA1#0!..*.H...
11  000000a0: 0109 0116 1473 7570 706f 7274 4066 7261  .....support@fra
12  000000b0: 6e6b 3464 642e 636f 6d30 1e17 0d31 3230  nk4dd.com0...120
13  000000c0: 3832 3230 3532 3635 345a 170d 3137 3038  822052654Z..1708
14  000000d0: 3231 3035 3236 3534 5a30 4a31 0b30 0906  21052654Z0J1.0..
15  000000e0: 0355 0406 1302 4a50 310e 300c 0603 5504  .U....JP1.0...U.
16  000000f0: 080c 0554 6f6b 796f 3111 300f 0603 5504  ...Tokyo1.0...U.
17  00000100: 0a0c 0846 7261 6e6b 3444 4431 1830 1606  ...Frank4DD1.0..
18  00000110: 0355 0403 0c0f 7777 772e 6578 616d 706c  .U....www.exampl
19  00000120: 652e 636f 6d30 5c30 0d06 092a 8648 86f7  e.com0\0...*.H..

20  00000130: 0d01 0101 0500 034b 0030 4802 4100 9bfc  .......K.0H.A...

21  00000140: 6690 7984 42bb ab13 fd2b 7bf8 de15 12e5  f.y.B....+{.....
22  00000150: f193 e306 8a7b b8b1 e19e 26bb 9501 bfe7  .....{....&.....
23  00000160: 30ed 6485 02dd 1569 a834 b006 ec3f 353c  0.d....i.4...?5<
24  00000170: 1e1b 2b8f fa8f 001b df07 c6ac 5307 0203  ..+.........S...
25  00000180: 0100 0130 0d06 092a 8648 86f7 0d01 0105  ...0...*.H......
26  00000190: 0500 0381 8100 14b6 4cbb 8179 33e6 71a4  ........L..y3.q.
27  000001a0: da51 6fcb 081d 8d60 ecbc 18c7 7347 59b1  .Qo....`....sGY.
28  000001b0: f220 48bb 61fa fc4d ad89 8dd1 21eb d5d8  . H.a..M....!...
29  000001c0: e5ba d6a6 36fd 7450 83b6 0fc7 1ddf 7de5  ....6.tP......}.
30  000001d0: 2e81 7f45 e09f e23e 79ee d730 31c7 2072  ...E...>y..01. r
31  000001e0: d958 2e2a fe12 5a34 45a1 1908 7c89 475f  .X.*..Z4E...|.G_
32  000001f0: 4a95 be23 214a 5372 da2a 052f 2ec9 70f6  J..#!JSr.*./..p.
33  00000200: 5bfa fddf b431 b2c1 4a9c 0625 43a1 e6b4  [....1..J..%C...
34  00000210: 1e7f 869b 1640                           .....@
```

Notice that in Line 20, we have, starting at the 7th byte, the sequence `03 4B 00 30 48 02 41 00...` which indicates

- a [bitstring (`0x03`)](https://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node124.html)
- of 75 (`0x4B`) bytes,
- which starts with the byte `00`.

If we ignore this first byte and look at the rest of this bitstring, we can parse the bytes according to the DER encoding rules as a sequence of 72 (`0x48`) bytes, which encode the modulus and exponent of the RSA public key as integers.

We notice that the modulus itself begins with `02 41 00 ...`, indicating

- an [integer (`0x02`)](https://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node124.html)
- of 65 (`0x41`) bytes
- and also starting with the byte `00`.

My question is, why are these bytes here? For the modulus, which is interpreted as an integer, this null byte shouldn't be a problem. However, at the beginning of a sequence, it seems to indicate an EOC tag, which doesn't make sense, since the cert is DER encoded.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASN.1 **BIT STRING** can be any length, so the DER/BER encoding rounds up to a multiple of 8 (an integral number of octets) and prefixes one octet containing the count of added padding bits. Since this BIT STRING value is itself a DER encoding and thus already a multiple of 8 bits, the **padding count** is 00.

ASN.1 **INTEGER is signed**, and the DER/BER encoding is two's complement big-endian. Your N value 9BFC...5307 has a magnitude that is an exact multiple of 8 bits; this is common since most RSA moduli are deliberately chosen to make their size in bits a power of 2 higher than 2<sup>3</sup>, or a small multiple thereof, in your case 512. For this to be represented as a signed number a 0-bit must be prefixed, and since the encoding must be integral octets in fact we prefix a full 00 octet.

Back in the 1990s when RSADSI established a series of Public Key Cryptographic Standards (PKCS) using a good deal of ASN.1, Burt Kaliski wrote a "Layman's Guide" that covered a lot of useful details about ASN.1 quickly; see especially 5.4 and 5.7 in [this apparently definitive reference](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.6.6585) or [this more convenient but uncertainly permanent one](http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/layman.html).